# Consolidate duplicate WPF Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Apologies if the title doesn't make much sense but I couldn't think of a good wording.

Basically I have a user control where many controls have the binding:

```
<TextBox.IsEnabled>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AndLogicMultiValueConverter}">
           <Binding Path="Binding1" />
           <Binding Path="Binding" Converter="{StaticResource BoolToOppositeBoolConverter}"  />
     </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.IsEnabled>
```

This is repeated numerous times and makes the xaml look pretty untidy, i'm not sure whether it will also have a performance hit?

Is there any way to put this binding in the usercontrol resources and then bind to that?

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) with a [`Setter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.aspx) for `IsEnabled` with that binding?